# ORTE_ERROR_LOG: The system limit on number of pipes a process can open was reached in file odls_default_module.c at line 621

Tags: c, mpi

I am working on my project, I am using CUDA-Aware MPI in it. I basically have two different sizes of datasets, which is in CSV format (Let's just consider that I have small and large Dataset). Small dataset has 20 rows in it and Larger Dataset has 376 rows. I create the number of processes based on the number of rows in that particular dataset.

PC Specifications

- CPU : Intel® Xeon(R) Silver 4114 CPU @ 2.20GHz × 40
- OS : Ubuntu 21.10

When I try to run my program with smaller dataset it works perfectly fine(I created 20 different processes to work).

But when I try to run it with larger dataset it asked me to use `--oversubscribe`

So after using `--oversubscribe` it gives me this error :

```
[lenovo-ThinkStation-P720:136633] [[13842,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: The system limit on number of pipes a process can open was reached in file odls_default_module.c at line 621
```

the above error occurs 44 times, and then this appears

`mpirun: Forwarding signal 18 to job`

and stops executing and doesn't exit.

So I have tried to replicate it with simple MPI program (*just prints the rank of the process*) , So I basically did trail and error till where its going to work good. I have oversubscribed till -np 272 and after that it fails to run and gives me same error

I am not sure but I probably think it's to much load on each processor.

I just want to know that why does it fail and what I should be doing instead !

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks !!

Comment: according to the error message, you reached an OS limit. Your approach is wrong: the number of MPI processes should be independent of the number of rows in the dataset, so you should really update your code so it works with max one MPI task per core.

Comment: Thanks @GillesGouaillardet that's really helpful, Will do that definitely.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this on a dual socket machine with 384 threads (with -use-hwthread-cpus set).  `ulimit -n 2048` allowed the test to run.  The default here is 1024.